# How do I find A if I have the transpose of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

So I'm thinking about this problem

[image]

I know that $(A^T)^T=A$ but when I have a coefficient like in this problem above, what do I do?

Comment: $(\lambda A)^T = \lambda A^T$.

Comment: So from your comment @CameronWilliams, should I just divide the matrix  by 2 and then transpose it?

Comment: Sure, or transpose then divide by two. Whichever way you want to do it!

Comment: Or you can even just transpose both sides of the equality as you mention in the question $2A = ((2A)^T)^T = \begin{pmatrix} 8 & -1 \\ 4 &6 \end{pmatrix}^T$.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much @Rammus :)

Comment: If you know how to evaluate $(2A)^T$ for a given matrix $A$, then you know how to check whether an answer to this problem is correct. It's the same thought process as "find $x$ if $3x+5=11$". Be confident :)

Comment: That was a good point @Karl. Didn't think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning my comment hint into into an "answer":

Hint: $(\lambda A)^T = \lambda A^T$.

Comment: Thank you so much @CameronWilliams

Comment: Happy to help! If you liked either my answer or Arnaldo's, please accept one of them to prevent this post from being bumped to the front page unnecessarily in the future by Community. (This happens to questions that do not have an accepted answer.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

You also can try this,
$$[(2A)^T]^T=2A.$$

Comment: I see! Thank you @Arnado! :)